# mongoid, how to merge result with map/reduce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I try to use out reduce but I do not know how to call output .
Example:

```
@results = Article.collection.map_reduce(map, reduce, :out => 'test')

@results.find()
 => <Mongo::Cursor:0x2c276c4 namespace='myapp_development.test' @selector={} @cursor_id=>
```

When I try :

```
@results1 = Article.collection.map_reduce(map, reduce, :out =>{reduce: 'test'}
```

Expected result is duplicate @results. But I run @results1.find().to_a I see it equal with @results

And how can I call result by namespace in rubyrails using mongoid ??

Comment: Try `@results.to_a`. What is it?

Comment: @sergio: My question is how to call collection result 'test' . and way to use output 'reduce' . Thanks for reply :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TLTR: You can't have a duplicate result.

When a map function emit something, and when the reduce function return something, it is a couple [key, value].
When stored into a collection, for each entry, the output is represented as a Mongoid document like this :

```
{
  "_id" => "my key",
  "value" => "my value"
}
```

I want to be clear on that point : the Key is stored as the `_id`, so it is **unique** in a collection.

See the [Map/Reduce output options](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-Outputoptions) to know how MongoDb can deal with duplicate key when outputing into an existing collection :

- **replace (the default) :** the content of existing collection is dropped, and the output go into it
- **merge :** The existing collection is kept. When a result with the same Key (the _id) exists, it is replaced with the freshly map/reduced one.
- **reduce :** The existing collection is kept. When a result with the same Key (the _id) exists, MongoDB takes it, and takes the freshly map/reduced one, and run the reduce function against the two of them, and stores the result.

So, you can't have a duplicate result.

**Edit:**

I respond here to "Can you show me how to apply output reduce , and how to call a collection result" (because the response is quite long) :

There is many way. Let's take an example among others :

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :tags, :type => Array
end

Post.create(:tags => ["Dog", "Cat"])
Post.create(:tags => ["Dog", "Puppy"])
```

Let's map/reduce this :

```
map = %Q{
  function() {
    this.tags.forEach(function(tag){
      emit(tag, { count: 1 });
    }); 
  }
}

reduce = %Q{
  function(key, values) {
    var result = { count: 0 };
    values.forEach(function(value) {
      result.count += value.count;
    });
    return result;
  }
}

Post.map_reduce(map, reduce).out(replace: "tags")
```

Ok, that put the result in a collection named "tags" overwriting it.

We can create a Model to access it :

```
class Tag
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :value, :type => Hash
end

dog = Tag.find("Dog")
dog._id # => "Dog"
dog.value["count"] # => 2
```

For the fun, let's say you keep the timestamp of the last time you did the map/reduce. You can do with `reduce` to do it incrementaly :

```
Post.where(:created_at.gt => Time.at(my_timestamp)).map_reduce(map, reduce).out(reduce: "tags")
```

** Edit: fixed map function **

Comment: Can you show me how to apply output reduce , and how to call a collection result. 
Ex: <Mongo::Cursor:0x2c276c4 namespace='myapp_development.test' @selector={} @cursor_id=>
I try run in console : myapp_development.test => undefined myapp_development
db.test => undefined db ....
Thanks :D

Comment: I answered directly in the response (comments are too tricky).

Comment: ahhh, why I use .map_reduce(map, reduce).out(reduce: "tags") I get an error 
Mongo::OperationFailure: Database command 'mapreduce' failed: (assertion: ''out' has to be a string or an object'; assertionCode: '13606'; errmsg: 'db assertion failure'; ok: '0.0')
I using mongoid ver 2.4.11 and mongo 1.6.2

Comment: Ah, I gave an example of Mongoid 3. For 2.4, it is `MyModel.collection.map_reduce(map, reduce, options)`. This function is a pass-through the driver `map_reduce` function. You can find the options in http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#map_reduce-instance_method